# Can not get value from select Angular9

Tags: angular

There is modal window which is used for inserting data in DB. Data which should be inserted are name from text box and id from selected value from select tag

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
         placeholder="Item name..." [(ngModel)]="newItemEditor.name"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': newItemEditor.error }" (keyup.enter)="addItem()" />
        <div *ngIf="newItemEditor.error" class="invalid-feedback">
          {{ newItemEditor.error }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="productType">Product Type</label>
          <select class="form-control" ([ngModel])="newItemEditor.productType">
            <option  [value]="'item'" *ngFor="let item of productTypeVm.lists" >{{item.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and ts file is

```
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemVm, ItemsClient, ItemDto, CreateItemCommand, VersionsClient, VersionVM, ProductTypesClient, ProductTypeVm } from '../audit-api';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
        selector: 'app-item-component',
        templateUrl: './item.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
    })

export class ItemComponent{

        selectedPT:any;
        itemVm: ItemVm;
        productTypeVm: ProductTypeVm;
        faPlus = faPlus;
        newItemEditor: any = {};
        newItemModalRef: BsModalRef;

        constructor(private listsItemClient: ItemsClient, 
            private modalService: BsModalService,
            private listProductTypeClient: ProductTypesClient){
            listsItemClient.get()
            .subscribe(
                result =>
                {
                    this.itemVm = result;
                }
            )

            listProductTypeClient.get().subscribe(
                result => {
                    this.productTypeVm = result;
                }
            )
        }


    showNewListModal(template: TemplateRef<any>): void {
        this.newItemModalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
        setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("name").focus(),250);
    }

    newItemCancelled(): void{
        this.newItemModalRef.hide();

    }
    addItem():void{
        console.log(this.newItemEditor.productTypeId);
        let list = ItemDto.fromJS({
            id:null,
            name: this.newItemEditor.name,
            productTypeId: this.newItemEditor.productTypeId
        });

        this.listsItemClient.create(<CreateItemCommand>{name:this.newItemEditor.name, productTypeId: this.newItemEditor.productTypeId})
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.itemVm.lists.push(list);
                this.newItemModalRef.hide();
                this.newItemEditor={};
            },error => {
                let errors = JSON.parse(error.response);
                if(errors && errors.Title){
                    this.newItemEditor.error = errors.errors.Name[0];
                }
                setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("name").focus(), 250);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Main problem is newItemEditor.name is fetching value without any problem, but select tag don't get any data even if they are bind correctly, constantly I'm getting value for newItemEditor.productType as undifiend. I had tried to put `[value]="'item.id'"` and `([ngModel])= "newItemEditor.productTypeId"`
but at the end result is the same. What I did wrong ?
Regards,
Danijel

**UPDATE 1**
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rddhzi)

Comment: This doesn't look good: [value]="'item.id'" - you probably want to remove the single quotes there (otherwise is is just interpreted as the string 'item.id' and not the actual value.

Comment: I tried without single quotes, also tried to put [ngValue]... But no good results...

Comment: You might want to do a stackblitz for this..

Comment: Please check Update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `([ngModel])` on the select. It should be `[(ngModel)]`. Order of the brackets matter.

Comment: Thanks, to be honest didn't saw that at all :/, what a mistake...